# How to return observable from subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that returns an observable, items.
So one can use it as myService.items().subscribe().

In another service "service2" I want to create a method that will return an observable, it will call myService and act as a pipe so if one call service2.items().subscribe()
The items first will come from myService items, the items will be manipulated with service2, and the items will stream to subscriber.

Can it be done?
I manage to do so with event emitter, but I understand it is not a best practice to use event emitters in services.

Answer (score 1):

Your service 1 code

```
return service1Observable().map(Your changes for service 1)
```

Your service 2 code

```
return callService1().map(Your changes for service 2)
```

In your component, subscribe to service1 and service2 as needed. Do not move any manipulation into subscriber, keep everything inside service

Component 1

```
service1().subscribe()
```

Component 2

```
service2().subscrible()
```

PS: Would have been easier to answer and explain if you had shared some code in the question